# What is the name of the character $\wp$?

Tags: symbols, characters, letters

What is the name of the character whose code is $\wp$ ?

Thanks

Comment: “℘” U+2118 Script Capital P Unicode Character

Comment: Haha, any shorter name??

Comment: The `U+2118` is the unicode code of the character. “Unicode Character” is just there to say it's unicode, so it's a “Script Capital P”.

Comment: The letters “wp” stand for “Weierstrass p”. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - It's a script *lowercase* "p".

Comment: @Mico It certainly looks more lowercase than capital. That name is just what I got Googling a `℘`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik - You can't always trust Google. :-)

Comment: @Mico Unicode classes it as uppercase P, as do the ISO (and then HTML) entity sets, `&weierp;` is U+2118

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik -- That's **old** Unicode, version 3 or earlier.  Unicode from version 4 should have it as "Weierstrass p".  It's lowercase, and allegedly modeled after Weierstrass' handwriting.  (I was the culprit who caused the renaming correction, when I brought the STIX material to the Unicode Technical Committee.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Unicode corrected it to lowercase at the same time they renamed it.  If it looks like uppercase in the charts, I'll complain to Asmus Freytag and Ken Whistler.

Comment: @barbarabeeton its unicode name is still SCRIPT **CAPITAL** P though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Technically, you're correct; my bad.  But notice in the chart that the second line is also in all caps, preceded by an "X".  That is clear indication that they got the name wrong, and it's only because of the rule that once a name is published, it can never change.  Sigh.  (Wishful thinking on my part.)

Answer (score 7):

```html
  <character id="U02118" dec="8472" mode="math" type="alphabetic">
     <unicodedata category="So" combclass="0" bidi="ON" mirror="N" unicode1="SCRIPT P" mathclass="A" alias="weierstrass elliptic function"/>
     <afii>22A6</afii>
     <latex>\wp </latex>
     <mathlatex set="unicode-math">\wp</mathlatex>
     <Elsevier grid="bjo" ent="weierp">
        <desc>Weierstrass elliptic function</desc>
     </Elsevier>
     <AMS>\wp</AMS>
     <APS>weierp</APS>
     <AIP>weierp</AIP>
     <IEEE>\wp</IEEE>
     <Wolfram>WeierstrassP</Wolfram>
     <entity id="weierp" set="xhtml1-symbol">
        <desc>script capital P = power set = Weierstrass p</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="weierp" set="8879-isoamso">
        <desc>/wp - Weierstrass p</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="weierp" set="9573-1991-isoamso">
        <desc>/wp - Weierstrass p</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="weierp" set="9573-2003-isoamso">
        <desc>/wp - Weierstrass p</desc>
     </entity>
     <entity id="wp" set="mmlalias">
        <desc>alias ISOAMSO weierp</desc>
     </entity>
     <font name="ptmlucrm" pos="125"/>
     <description unicode="1.1">SCRIPT CAPITAL P</description>
  </character>
```

So generically it's a script P , but the `\wp` refers to its normal use to denote  Weierstrass elliptic functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions

Comment: But not an *ordinary* script p.  Not interchangeable with `\mathscr{p}`.

Answer (score 4):

The $\wp$ character is "℘" U+2118, as @Phelype Oleinik says.  The correct symbol name is "SCRIPT CAPITAL P".  According to the Unicode documentation, the letter is actually a lowercase p.  It may also be referred to "WEIERSTRASS ELLIPTIC FUNCTION"

Refer to:

[Easy to read U+2118 description](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2118/index.htm)

[Actual Unicode Source](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf)

Comment: There is actually a more complicated explanation.  In Unicode 2, the uppercase script P was probably intended to represent the power set, but when the STIX effort submitted the Weierstrass p, the Unicode Technical Committee determined that that was a more appropriate association.  (They probably should have instead assigned a new code for the Weierstrass p, and added text that linked U+2118 indisputably to the power set.  But they didn't.  Hence the confusion.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did not know that.  Very interesting.