# What does the symbol $\wp$ mean?

Tags: equations

I recently encountered a symbol `$\wp$`, and its meaning confuses me. For example, while `$\forall$`, `$\angle$` have a definite meaning in mathematics, so what does the symbol `$\wp$` mean?

Comment: One systematic way to lookup meanings is to lookup the csname in `unimath-symbols.pdf` and search for the corresponding unicode codepoint.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476660/what-is-the-name-of-the-character-wp/476665#476665but that's closed as off topic, (I'm not sure I agree with that) so only visible to users with high enough rep total.

Comment: @Symbol 1 thank you very much!

Comment: @David Carlisle I'm very sorry. I'm new here. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: @Zeta no need to apologise: there is no way you could have known about the duplicate since it appears deleted to new users. (I posted the comment above as I remembered the question and searched for it so added the link to save others searching, I was surprised to find it closed:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [Weierstrass's elliptic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions).

According to wikipedia, "this symbol was used already at least in 1890. The first edition of A Course of Modern Analysis by E. T. Whittaker in 1902 also used it."

Comment: thank you very much!